# Group points by street

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a group of about 10,000 POI that are all on streets in the same metropolitan area. I'm about to go through and information about each street from google maps (traffic lane widths).

Is there any way to quickly group POIs into the same street so that I can enter lane widths once for all point on a given street?

Comment: Have you tried Spatial Join (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm)?